# Native library already loaded - without restarting JVM

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classloader

I have well know problem: Native libray already loaded in another classloader in Spring Boot app.
There was already such discussion here. I read it. I couldn't find an answer
for one particular question:

Is there any way to deploy a new version without restarting the
machine? (it's production in my case).

I tried to:

1 remove jar from project libs and redeploy

2 comment static initializer block and redeploy

3 remove jar, comment static initializer

No success. Is there any way to fix project setup so it can be deployed without
restarting a jvm?

Comment: Do you considered to have two production servers behind a load-balancer? Then you can shut down and upgrade one machine, and after that the other - no downtime.

Comment: Would be nice, but unfortunately not an option in my case

Comment: You could try to run GC/runFinalization in a loop, but the only guaranteed way to load a native library "twice" is to rename/copy the native library and load it again.